# How to use capture group in rsyslog?

Tags: linux, logging, syslog, rsyslog

For now, I want to analyze logs from python's lib `logging`, and I want to filter logs by `logger`'s name which is an attribute of `logger`.

I think I can use regex to extract `logger`'s name from `msg` or `rawmsg`. But the problem is it is difficult to locate as rsyslog just support a basic regex. I have tried something like look forward group and look backward group. And I cannot find the usage of even a simple capture group.

Is there a capture group support in rsyslog? BTW, I'm using centos6.9, so rsyslog's version is v5.

Comment: Please provide a more explicit example of what you have as messages and what you want to match and log. There are capture groups in rsyslog. Check out a recent [reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402300/119298) I made on Unix&Linux.

Comment: @meuh Thanks for your comment but for now we abort to use `rsyslog` as `SysLogHandler` in python2.6 has an issue about `unicode`. Anyway, thanks again.